# Neural Network doesn't match the expected output

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to build a Neural Network from scratch, using only numpy. I have the following code and functions. However, the output after the training is not matching the expected output that i have (using XOR as an example). I think one of my functions is not correct but cannot figure out the mistake. The output I get is, for example: [[0.73105858], [0.53336314],[0.79343002],[0.5786911 ]], which is not close to the expected output [0,0,0,1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't so any issues with your code, but here are some thing you should have in mind:

Your neural network is trained for 2 iterations, with a learning rate of 0.01. This means that your network is only updated 2 times with a small rate of improvement resulting in an undertrained neural network. Also, your always using a tensor of the size 4*4 for input, meaning that the neural network is only updated for the average of all samples, hence the result that just seems like an average.

For improvement, my suggestion would be to increase the number of iterations and also increase the number of samples for each iterations, also making sure that each iteration has more than one update. Still, i believe that you won't get 100% accurate results, since you are only using one linear layer for XOR, which can't be solved with just one linear system. You could consider adding another layer for better results.